# summation of second table grouped by results of first table

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL syntax, how would I write a query to return the following (I am including the two table descriptions and the relationship between them):

```
TABLE_A (ID, DATE, TABLE_C_ID)
TABLE_B (ID, AMOUNT, TABLE_A_ID)
TABLE_C (ID)
```

I want to return the following, with the specified limitations:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_A.ID, 
    TABLE_A.DATE 
    (SUM TABLE_B.AMOUNT 
         FROM TABLE_B 
         WHERE TABLE_B.ID = TABLE_A.ID) 
    FROM TABLE_A, TABLE_B 
    WHERE TABLE_A.TABLE_C_ID = 123
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with doing it thus?:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_A.ID, 
    TABLE_A.DATE,
    SUM( TABLE_B.AMOUNT ) AS AMOUNT

FROM TABLE_A

INNER JOIN TABLE_B 
ON TABLE_B.ID = TABLE_A.ID

WHERE TABLE_A.TABLE_C_ID = 123

GROUP BY TABLE_A.ID, 
    TABLE_A.DATE
```

Comment: Woops, never mind... I was not saving some data properly. Fixed, thanks!